# Set faultCode to SENDER in a custom SoapFault?

Tags: soap, spring-ws, custom-exceptions, soapfault

I want to throw my own custom exceptions through Spring-WS.
I write my Exception class like this :

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.CUSTOM, customFaultCode = "{http://www.myorg.com/test}INVALID_INPUT_DATA")
public class InvalidDataException extends Exception
{
    public InvalidDataException(String errorMsg)
    {
    super(errorMsg);
    }

    public InvalidDataException(Throwable t)
    {
    super(t);
    }
}
```

When my service throws this exception with a text parameter, I get a good soapFault with my customFaultCode as a subCode :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
            <env:Subcode>
               <env:Value xmlns:ns1="http://www.myorg.com/test">ns1:INVALID_INPUT_DATA</env:Value>
            </env:Subcode>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">WTF! Something wrong with your input data...</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But I don't want to have a faultCode **env:Receiver**, I'd like to change it to **env:Sender** because the problem with input data is on client side !
But I don't know how to do. If I change faultCode to **FaultCode.SENDER** in my exception class, I get well a **env:Sender** faultCode but my customFaultCode is not considered and I get :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">WTF! Something wrong with your input data...</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I saw in the javadoc of SimpleSoapExceptionResolver that the fault code is always set to Receiver (for SOAP 1.2).
How can I change this ?

Stieuma

Comment: sorry, I tried to edit my original post to say hello but it doesn't work... :(

Comment: Can you show us your spring configuration file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [soap spring ws -how to customise <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode> to <faultcode>some error code.eg(a number)</faultcode>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395104/soap-spring-ws-how-to-customise-faultcodesoapenvserver-faultcode-to-fault)