# soap spring ws -how to customise <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode> to <faultcode>some error code.eg(a number)</faultcode>

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am using soap spring ws to create a soap webservice and i have successfully 
created.Now i was doing the fault implementation in this soap service and i was 
able to do it with a class that i created like the following

```
public class ServiceSoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver extends SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver
```

and inside the following overridden function,

```
@Override
 protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {
//code for adding fault details

    Result result = fault.addFaultDetail().getResult();

            // marshal
            try {
                 JAXBContext.newInstance(ExceptionListType.class).createMarshaller().marshal(exceptionList, result);

}
```

i created the custom soap fault object and returned that.
This returned custom soap fault is coming inside the detail tag.
so my fault looks like this.

```
<soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID NUMBER</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns5:exceptionListType xmlns:ns5="http://wellpoint.com/esb/header/v2">
               <ns5:errorCount>1</ns5:errorCount>
               <ns5:Exception>
                  <ns5:UUID> 889c-6f73671534af</ns5:UUID>
                  <ns5:timestamp>09/04/2015 05:47:40</ns5:timestamp>
                  <ns5:node>mynode</ns5:node>
                  <ns5:process>JAVA</ns5:process>
                  <ns5:component>Unknown Component</ns5:component>
                  <ns5:code>5009</ns5:code>
                  <ns5:severity>FATAL</ns5:severity>
                  <ns5:message>An unexpected server error occurred: INVALID   NUMBER</ns5:message>
               </ns5:Exception>
            </ns5:exceptionListType>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
```

now what i want to do is i have an error code associated with the above error and it is coming inside the code tag.But i need this error code come inside this tag

```
<faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
```

like

```
<faultcode>5009</faultcode>
```

.I have had a lot of googling and no luck.I know it is not a good practice to have a value other than the predefined set of values available for this.But my client requierment is this.
Please help me if anyone knows an answer.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a way to solve the issue.
inside the customizeFault method, i put code like below.

```
    SoapFaultDefinition soapFaultDefinition = new SoapFaultDefinition();
    String ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    QName FAULT_NAME = new QName(ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI, "5999, "e");
    //      soapFaultDefinition.setFaultStringOrReason("--" + ex);
    //      soapFaultDefinition.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    soapFaultDefinition.setFaultCode(FAULT_NAME);
    super.setDefaultFault(soapFaultDefinition);
```